# Tensor Product: Preliminary

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let $S$ and $T$ be bounded operators over a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Define their tensor product $S\otimes T$ as acting on $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H}$ by $S\otimes T(x\otimes y):=Sx\otimes Ty$ and then extended by linearity to the dense subspace of finite linear combination of such $x\otimes y$ and after proving boundedness by continuity to all of $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H}$.

**How do I prove there that it is indeed bounded on the dense subspace?**

The problem is that one has to consider finite *linear combinations* of these $x\otimes y$.
I remember from the proof of boundedness for the creation and annihilation operators over Fock space that the trick was to reduce quadratic expressions to linear ones via $\|x\|=\sup_{\|\hat{z}\|=1}|\langle\hat{z},x\rangle|$. However I don't know how and wether at all this works here.

Now, let $A$ and $B$ be selfadjoint operators but not necessarily bounded and define $A\otimes B$ on an appropriate subspace.

**How do I prove that it is essentially selfadjoint?**

To show symmetry is a quite straightforward but selfadjointness...

Comment: You should try to find a better title...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I was rather thinking about closing it as I splitted this old thread into several new ones, should I? *(Tensor Product: Denseness, Closability, Boundedness, etc.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove boundedness of $S\otimes T$, it suffices to prove it when $S$ and $T$ are unitaries (since the unitaries span $\mathcal{B}(H)$. Now if
$$
z = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\otimes y_i
$$
where $\{y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n\}$ are orthogonal. So
$$
\|(S\otimes T)(z)\|^2 = \|\sum_{i=1}^n S(x_i)\otimes T(y_i)\|^2
$$
Since $\{y_i\}$ are orthogonal
$$
= \sum_{i=1}^n \|S(x_i)\otimes T(y_i)\|^2
$$
$$
= \sum_{i=1}^n \|S(x_i)\|^2 \|T(y_i)\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^2 \|y_i\|^2 = \|z\|^2
$$
Hence, $\|S\otimes T\| = 1$

Comment: Can you explain how the span works? Is it similar to the decomposition into selfadjoints: $T=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^*)+i\frac{1}{2i}(T-T^*)$

Comment: In addition, if $T = T^{\ast}$ and $\|T\| \leq 1$, then $T\pm i\sqrt{1-T^2}$ are both unitaries and $T$ is their average.

Comment: So you do split it sort of into: $T=(\frac{\Re{T}}{\|\Re{T}\|})_{+}+(\frac{\Re{T}}{\|\Re{T}\|})_{-}+i(\frac{\Im{T}}{\|\Im{T}\|})_{+}+i(\frac{\Im{T}}{\|\Im{T}\|})_{-}$